# Creating the Leaflet map offline(load the leaflet tiles without internet)

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet-plugins

I have created the Leaflet map which works in online. But now my requirement is to create the Leaflet open street map in offline.

How do I load the Leaflet map offline?

Comment: Can anyone help me to create the offline leaflet map

Comment: Look for keyword `offline` amongst Leaflet plugins: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html.

Comment: I have asked you even though I did not get any solution

Comment: And what you didn't like with these two: https://github.com/robertomlsoares/leaflet-offline, https://github.com/allartk/leaflet.offline?